# Vs code jupyter notebook hints not working well

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, intellisense

the problem is that when working with code in jupiter notebook in vs code, hints for dictionary keys in new cells do not appear, although they used to work correctly. At the moment, hints only work with a string-digit, neither Cyrillic, Latin, nor ordinary numbers do not pop up. I'm talking about a hint when you write

```
dict['
```

Just need to return all the hints. Remarkably, I have already tried to delete vs code and python, and revised the settings.json and looked through about 95% of all settings, it seems, but I can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

please install the pylance extension (for language features such as refactoring) and add the following settings in `settings.json` then try again:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the dictionary keys display when entering a construction "dict["?